# Why won't my HTML page print according to my CSS document?

Tags: html, css, printing

So basically, I have my CSS document that is stopping things from being printed.

Heres my CSS:

```
/* Making the page A4 compatible */

body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}

* 
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page 
{
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 2cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.subpage 
{
    height: 237mm;
}

@page 
{
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}

@media print 
{
    .page 
    {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

I made the page perfectly A4 compatible, while stopping basically everything from being printed besides a div that has the class of `page`.

I then call my print via `window.print();` from a button far outside of this div, which is just inside of the closing `body` tag.

Although, I am getting 4 pages being printed. One that is perfect, two that are blank, and one with just the button on it?

All these pages have the annoying footer on them with the URL, date, time and page number. I searched everywhere and this bit of code was meant to remove this, although it didn't do anything at all:

```
@page 
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to why this is happening?

Comment: You have positioned your button a "far outside" the `.page` div so in your media print styles try hiding the button and it's container (and any extra content not within the `.page` div) with `display:none`

Comment: @Pete - Thanks for that, I'll give it a try. Although, that still doesn't solve why the footer stuff is being printed on each page?

Comment: THis [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="Button1" name="b_print" type="button" runat="server" class="ipt" onclick="printdiv(divIDtoprint);" value=" Print "/>

<script lang="javascript">
function printdiv(printpage) {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
```

Basically just temporarily removes the other stuff on the page, prints whatever you want to print, then puts the old page back in it's place.

Comment: That's actually quite a smart approach. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I am receiving this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined `

Comment: Whoops, fixed it. That is a great solution, and it removed the problem I was having with many pages being printed. Although, it did not solve the footer issue.

Comment: Simply put the footer outside of the div you're printing in a new div with ID let's say "footerdiv" and give it ít's own position in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the position of your Page No.

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
  // you may have to change this right to left or center as per how it is printed
    content: "";
  }
}
```